# Adding custom method to all Spring data Mongo repositories - No property [methodName] found for type

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to add generic method `update` to all my Mongo repositories.

Here is my code:

**BaseMongoRepository.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseMongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {

    void update(T entity, ID id);
}
```

**BaseMongoRepositoryImpl.java**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class BaseMongoRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements BaseMongoRepository<T, ID> {

    private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public BaseMongoRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata, MongoTemplate mongoOperations) {

        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }

    public void update(T entity, ID id) {

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));

        Document doc = new Document();
        mongoOperations.getConverter().write(entity, doc);
        Update update = Update.fromDocument(new Document("$set", doc)); // Update.fromDocument(doc);

        mongoOperations.updateFirst(query, update, entity.getClass());
    }
}
```

**MongoDbConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseMongoRepositoryImpl.class)
public class MongoDbConfig {
    // ...
}
```

**FeedbackMongoRepository**

```
public interface FeedbackMongoRepository extends BaseMongoRepository<FeedbackEntity, String> {
}
```

But no matter what I try I always end up with this error during application startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'feedbackMongoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property update found for type FeedbackEntity!
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are the property name and method name in sync in FeedbackEntity?

Comment: @ApprenticeWST this is a custom repository and method. I should be able to use any name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `@EnableMongoRepositories` was in different package than repositories. I resolved this by adding `basePackages` parameter:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(
    basePackages = "cz.connect.server",
    repositoryBaseClass = BaseMongoRepositoryImpl.class)
```